# PL SQL - Sequentially update only number in varchar

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an existing table with data that is varchar. These codes were pre-determined by other-than-me so I cannot change them.

Every year I will need to run an insert statement which takes the previous year's data/codes and roll-them-over with the new year on them.

Example of existing data used for year 2019: CodeA19, CodeB19, CodeC19, CodeE19 etc

What I need to be able to do is sequentially add + 1 to the each code to change it to the new year (for 2020 in this case): CodeA20, CodeB20, CodeC20, CodeE20 etc

I've tried searching for regexpressions to do this but have had no luck on my own. I can't seem to find a way to separate out the mixed values to add to the numeric sequence.

Oracle db, PL sql, using SQL Dev

Thanks!

Comment: You want to select all rows with codes ending on 19 and insert these again with the code ending on 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to find values ending with the previous year, extract the remaining part, and tack on the new year; with hard-coded values something like:

```
select regexp_replace(code, '(.*)19$', '\1') as root,
       regexp_replace(code, '(.*)19$', '\1') || '20' as result
from your_table
where regexp_like(code, '(.*)19$');
```

or based on the actual current year, assuming you run it during the new year:

```
select regexp_replace(code, '(.*)' || to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'RR') || '$', '\1') as root,
       regexp_replace(code, '(.*)' || to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'RR') || '$', '\1')
         || to_char(sysdate, 'RR') as result
from your_table
where regexp_like(code, '(.*)' || to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'RR') || '$');
```

both of which currently get:

```
ROOT       RESULT    
---------- ----------
CodeA      CodeA20   
CodeB      CodeB20   
CodeC      CodeC20   
CodeE      CodeE20
```

and then use that as an insert:

```
insert into your_table (code)
select regexp_replace(code, '(.*)' || to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'RR') || '$', '\1')
         || to_char(sysdate, 'RR') as result
from your_table
where regexp_like(code, '(.*)' || to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'RR') || '$');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78295c830a66edee172799ea6b9bcd63)

The regexp pattern is a bit naive, but works for the examples; if you have more complicated values that might trip it up, or only want to match certain prefixes, then you would need to adapt that.

If the only numbers are the two-digit years at the end then you could simplify to use `replace` instead of `regexp_replace`, as Gordon suggested:

```
insert into your_table (code)
select replace(code, to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'RR'), to_char(sysdate, 'RR')) as result
from your_table
where code like to_char(add_months(sysdate, -12), '"%"RR');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3444579d757a447bd04757626c5e6172)

... but that may be a big 'if'.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has offered help. I think I need to be more clear, the code type isn't the word code, that was just for the alpha numeric example.

There are several hundred codes with different names in them, examples:

abdcef19
bedef19
aofdjkle19
asljenvidke19

So doing a regexp to replace a single alpha value won't work.  

The only variable which will always remain constant is the year which is displayed as 19 (for 2019), 20 (for 2020) etc.

Any thoughts?

I'm trying to future proof this for myself and anyone I might hand it off to.

Comment: Alex, your replace statement worked with one hitch that I didn't notice at first, about 13 of my "codes" have characters after the year as well, example:

ABCD19
vs
ABCD19Q1

Comment: I wasn't assuming 'code' was in the value, but I picked 'code' as the dummy column name, which might have been confusing. If you still only have years and quarter numbers, so you can safely replace all two-digit values, then I think just changing the final term from `'"%"RR'` to `'"%"RR"%"'`. Or again you can do more advanced checks with regex, to include and keep the quarter part, but sounds like that isn't necessary.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't trying to imply you didn't know, just that I wasn't clear, I'm mid-level at-best with SQL right now and trying to learn more.

That did the trick, it returned all the values I was looking for and had them properly formatted. 

Thank you Alex, your knowledge is greatly appreciated.  Out of curiosity, what does the "RR" do specifically?

Comment: @ScottReschke [RR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F) is like YY but moves the Y2K problem to mid-century.

Comment: Using YY or RR doesn't make any difference in this case, but as it matters for `to_date()` converting the other way, I find it slightly safer to just always use it. (When 2-digit years cannot be avoided, that is - using 4-digit years is preferable anyway.)

Comment: Agreed, as a date to string format it makes no difference. As a 2-digit string to date format, '49' becomes '2149' from 2050. Let me be the first to predict a Y50 apocalypse.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - we have to survive the 2039 epoch-alypse first *8-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest method is `replace`:

```
update t
    set code = replace(code, '19', '20')
    where code like '%19';
```

This assumes that codes do not have numbers.

Note:  This seems like a very strange data model, if you are changing existing values liek this.